# Compare the results of my Search Engine with google

Tags: seo, search-engine, google-search-console

Here I designed a search engine that works with my  algorithm
 http://imperialisticsearch.com/
 I would like to know, How can I efficiently compare the results of my search engine with google results?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Quality of search is evaluated manually by people: Search Engine Evaluators. Google hires them to check search results.